# How to have badges on mediawiki articles pages?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

Most badge creators just creates static image and force us to download the graphic. shields.io is only for projects. We need to show dynamic badges with just a number on it on our articles pages in our mediawiki. Mediawiki has an extension which uses OpenBadges for users only, but we need to show badges with only numbers on it on our mediawiki articles pages. How is it possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you explain what you are trying to use badges for?

Comment: The wiki is about games. Each game, one article page. The number on badges shows the rating of the game on that page. @Tgr

Comment: Are you looking for something like [userboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Userboxes) but with dynamic content? Are you trying to write your own extension or finding something that already exists?